# ipython - exiting debugging in loop

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

Let's say I set a breakpoint inside of a loop to see the value as below:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Tracer

for i in range(1,100,1):
     a = i #to see the value of a
     Tracer()()
```

Then, when I type "q" in ipdb, the loop just continues and I can never get out of debugging mode until the loop finishes.

Is there a way to get out of the loop from the debugging mode in this case? If I am using a wrong method, what's the proper way of setting a breakpoint in a loop in iPython?

Comment: Try adding -X:FullFrames to your command-line and see if it helps?

Comment: I tried "q -X:FullFrames" but it did not help. Any other suggestions? I wonder what's the proper way of doing this.

Comment: try restart instead of q.